# Advantage of a photodiode compared to a photoconductor

Tags: semiconductor-physics, photoelectric-effect

Physically, a photodiode and a photoconductor base on the same principle: Lifting charge carriers from the valence into the conductor band.

As this principle is already used in photoconductors which, if I understood correctly, are only made out of a single doped material, I wonder, how photodiodes benefit from being consist of two doped materials.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that the main advantage is speed. You can bias a photodiode, creating a thin depletion area with a large electric field across it. A photon interacting in this space will knock off an electron that moves in the strong field, generating a fast signal. And absent a signal, you can keep the dark current very low.

Of course the natural extension of this is the SiPM (silicon photomultiplier) which takes that phenomenon a step further by creating thousands of tiny “micro cells”, each of which is a single photodiode that is biased above breakdown voltage. A photon now generates not just a single electron, but an avalanche (until the device saturates in the way of a Geiger sensor) - creating a fast and (at low photon density) linear response.

These devices are now the standard in many LIDAR applications as well as some medical imagine devices (PET scanners), where fast response to low signal levels is important.

Comment: does that mean that photoconductors are slow? What is the physical difference?

Comment: @Ben There is no strong electric field in photoconducting detectors. In a diod, the charge carriers are quickly swept out of the depletion area by the field. In a photoconductor, speed is limited by the recombination time.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. But how would I measure any signal in a photoconductor when there is no current produced?

Comment: @Ben ah - but there is a current ... in one simple implementation, a photoconductor circuit measures the impedance by applying a voltage and measuring the resulting current.

Comment: Does it matter if the photon hits the pn region?